# cdata is different changingin each step of a loop

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make a video in Matlab, but after I run my programm there is an Error message appearing. 
The Error says:

```
    Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo (line 369)
    All 'cdata' fields in FRAMES must be the samse size
```

My Code is

```
    v=VideoWriter('myvideo.avi','Uncompressed AVI'); 
    v.FrameRate=6; 
    open(v)

    startdate=1;
    enddate=10;

    for s=startdate:enddate  
       fig=figure;
       set(fig, 'position',[1 1 750 525])  

       % ....  (plotting of my data )

       g(s)=getframe(fig);
       size(g(s).cdata)
       close(fig)
    end

    writeVideo(v,f)
    close(v)
```

I have tried `pause` before `getframe` but the error occurs nearly everytime. Has someone an idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Did you check to see what size `g(s).cdata` is each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this structure

```
v = VideoWriter('namefile.avi','Uncompressed AVI');
v.FrameRate = 6;
open(v);

startdate=1;
enddate=10;

fig=figure;
set(fig, 'position',[1 1 750 525])  

for s=startdate:enddate  

%your plotting code like
           %Z = randn(3);
           %surf(Z);

       currFrame = getframe(gcf);
       writeVideo(v,currFrame);
end

close(v);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the new structure worked very well and I haven't had any problem wih cdata anymore.
I just had to add `clf(fig,'reset')` after `getframe` because matlab was drawing over the old picture.

Comment: @birdy305 I supposed you didn't want 10 plot displays when recording the video: at this scope I wrote `fig = figure` and the `set` instruction outside the loop rather than inside. Please consider to accept the answer if it satisfies your needs.